# Can you get source code from React build files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React build files for my app but I have lost my source file, so I need to get source file from this build version. Is this possible? How can I do it?

I can test build version to change it. Add code and log, but I can't rebuild this.

Comment: It will depend on how you built it and whether you have source maps. Lesson is: use source control.

Comment: If you have source maps for your original project available you may be able to use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-unpack) to retrieve them. The lesson as highlighted by @jonrsharpe is to use source control always.

Answer (score 1):

**No** ,
You cannot directly retrieve from react build File. Browser can not understand the JSX syntax of React. So build file is generated after series of transformations using web pack or react-script and babel.

Comment: You could easily transform the `React.createElement` syntax back to JSX though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, most react website have source map files on build, you can find the components on debugger : `Main Thread /static/js`